# Cant showing .tpl from .php

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I am working on a web page, I validate empy textbox with jscript. I have a .tpl that references to the javascript and in the js I call a php using ajax. In the php I call another tpl, (the main menu). In the console, the response gives me the code of html, but it doesnt show the page.

Comment: welcome to SO. when you do not post your relevant pieces of code, we can not look at your code to find the error. so please, provide a working code sample. see also [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Well, the result of an AJAX call won't magically show on the page, no. You'll have to make it show on the page through Javascript.

Comment: Can you please show us the Code of JS with the ajax functionality which should be load the templateFile ?

Answer (score -1):

You must include tpl file in your PHP. Try to learn how Smarty templates work.